# What is the proper term for global nicknames such as "Dude", "Slick", "Jack", etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, nicknames, hailnames

Some people have the tendency to use words in a context similar to a pronoun, despite the word in question being an adjective, verb, whatever. Examples would be someone like Agent K in the film "Men in Black", who often referred to his junior agent "J" in such a way:

- Whatever, ***slick***, but let me tell you something.
- It's your show, ***chief***.

An historical example would be the hippy sub-culture of 1960's and 1970's America, which often used the expression "man" in this way.

- It's looooove, ***man***. Love sets you free.

Another example from that same time period would be the "Greaser" sub-culture, which used the proper name "Jack".

- Don't be a square, ***Jack***. Just ride.

In American English, what is the proper term for using words this way? I initially thought "nickname", but that's more of an individual thing. This use seems rather global and generalized.

Comment: The other question doesn't give an answer I'm entirely satisfied with ("colloquial vocative", really?) but if that's the answer, that's the answer.

Comment: I have just offered another answer to the original.

Comment: @KevinMark - yep, I like "appellation" much better, and that was my second thought after "nickname". Gave you a +1 on that answer.